# How to store the result of an select statement into a variable in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a condition like this:

```
IF @aaa = 'high'
set @bbb = select * from table1
else
set @bbb = select * from table2
```

I am going to use this variable (@bbb) throughout my stored procedure

is this possible to save a table into a variable?

I tried using temporary table but i am not able to assign it twice.

```
IF @aaa = 'high'
    set @bbb = select * into #temp from table1
    else
    set @bbb = select * into #temp from table2
```

it shows #temp is already declared.

Answer (score 2):

No, It is not work like that. You can declare a table variable and insert into inside it.

```
DECLARE @bbbTable TABLE(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    SampleColumn varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
insert into @bbbTable (Id,SampleColumn)
select Id,SampleColumn from table1
```

If the table1 and table2 are completely different tables, you should declare two different table variable;

```
DECLARE @bbbTable TABLE(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    SampleColumn varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
DECLARE @aaaTable TABLE(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    SampleColumn varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

IF @aaa = 'high'
    insert into @bbbTable (Id,SampleColumn)
    select Id,SampleColumn from table1
else
    insert into @aaaTable (Id,SampleColumn)
    select Id,SampleColumn from table2
```

Comment: except this way there is no other method i can do this?

Comment: No, unfortunetly. I am almost sure, this is the only way.

Comment: but i cant use this method because the else condition has another table with different datatype and column names

Comment: I updated my answer. There is no option expect declaring two different table variable.

Comment: Actually, what is your achieve ? If you provide more details, you can manage it in one variable.

Comment: i am going to use that variable(@bbb) through out my stored procedure to pass values to some queries and so. if i create 2 tables then how can i know each time that which condition has passed either if or else since it has 2 tables how do i know which table to use?

Comment: I think, you best option is creating a temp table and using it.

Comment: that too cannot be same temporary table name for both if and else condition

Comment: What would you expect ? You can't assign different tables to a single variable.

Comment: @AshwanthKA, you could store the result set of the different queries in an `XML` variable if the schema varies by table source. That said, using `SELECT *` and varying schema for downstream consumers looks to be a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

You can store only 1 Column/Row to a variable.So you can't say *.

Suppose I want to  store  the value of Column1 from TableA to a variable, I can use this

```
SELECT @MyVariable = Column1 FROM TableA
```

But I Can't Say

```
SELECT @MyVariable = * FROM TableA
```

Even if there is only 1 column in the Table TableA.

Also If there is more than 1 record returned by the Select condition, then it will assign the First value to the Variable.

Or What you need is to store the entire Rows, you can Either use a Temporary table or a table variable.

Temporary Table

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM TableA
```

Table Variable

```
DECLARE @MyVarTable TABLE
(
Column1 VARCHAR(50),
Column2 VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @MyVarTable 
(
Column1 ,
Column2
)
SELECT
Column1 ,
Column2
From MyTable
```

This Temporary Table and Table variable can be accessed in the same way you access the normal table using SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE Queries. Except :

Temporary tables are created for each session and automatically dropped when the session ends or the Query window is Closed

Table Variables exists only when you execute the Query. So before using the table variable in a query you need to declare the same

Answer (score 0):

You cant insert into a variable more than 1 value.
you can use Table Variable to reach your answer like this:

```
DELCARE @TableResult AS TABLE (Column1 INT, Column2 INT)

IF @aaa = 'high'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TableResult (Column1,Column2)
    SELECT Column1FromTable, Column2FromTable
    FROM   table1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TableResult (Column1,Column2)
    SELECT Column1FromTable, Column2FromTable
    FROM   table2
END
```

Of course you can declare more than 2 columns.

Comment: but both the table have different column name and datatypes.

Comment: so why do you want the results in 1 variable? what you wanna reach ? if the columns and data types are different it cant be in the same table.

Comment: you should create 2 Table variables